# Why Seq2SeqTrainer does not have a predict_dataset argument?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-hub, huggingface-trainer

I am using Seq2SeqTrainer for my experiments. But it only takes train_dataset & eval_dataset. To only do prediction without calculating eval metrics, how can I input predict_datadset (test data) ?